# Find Dialog box in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

is there find and replace dialog box in C#?

Comment: what exactly are you going to find for & replace in?

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio, yes, it's on the Edit menu. Or use Ctrl-F or Ctrl-H.

"In C#", no. If you need that functionality, you'll need to write it yourself, I'm afraid.

Comment: As for building it yourself, the dialog box isn't particularly interesting. The interesting part is figuring out how to perform a "search" against the underlying data bound to your GUI

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article on this which is on Code Project, it includes full source.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/889607/A-Rich-Find-And-Replace-Control-For-Almost-All-WPF